# Radio controls not showing in WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a link that opens a html page which has Radio buttons and other controls in it. It opens fine and shows all page contents when i open it in the default browser. However, when i try to open the same using WebBrowser.Navigate()  , the page that opens doesn't show the radio buttons which are present. Strange . Has anyone else encountere these kinds of issues. Kindly help.

Comment: Can you check if setting IsScriptEnabled = true; in WebBrowser would solve the issue?

Comment: I've tried it. Doesn't seem to work. Any other alternative that you could suggest would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you provide some code and maybe Url of the Page?

Comment: Hi, There was a problem in the way the html document was formatted. I manually created a page and radio buttons were seen properly.Thanks for ur input.

Comment: Thak you for the information. Also write an answer to this question and accept it - so that this problem is no longer unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html didn't have a DOCTYPE declaration. I declared the DOCTYPE and everything shows fine. The same html page without DTD shows everything fine on android and iOS. SOmehow IE requires the DTD.